# Boot drops into BusyBox/initramfs on Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, initramfs, busybox

I'm extremely new to the Ubuntu community and I wanted to revive an old PC to have it connected to my TV for movies and such!

I installed Ubuntu on a USB stick so I can then boot into Ubuntu to see if everything is fine, and then have it installed, also replacing the old corrupted Windows 7 from before.

However, (trying to) boot into Ubuntu results in this:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

It drops boot into BusyBox/initramfs.

Typing the command  `exit` results in *this*:

```
(initramfs) exit
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
/init: line 344: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
[  116.146799] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
[  116.146799]
[  116.146928] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[  116.147032] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. G31M-ES2L/G31M-ES2L, BIOS FF 10/13/2009
[  116.147149] Call Trace:
[  116.147198]  dump_stack+0x58/0x81
[  116.147250]  panic+0x94/0x1e6
[  116.147296]  do_exit+0xa1c/0xa20
[  116.147347]  do_group_exit+0x35/0x90
[  116.147402]  SyS_exit_group+0x16/0x20
[  116.147457]  do_fast_syscall_32+0x7f/0x1d0
[  116.147520]  entry_SYSENTER_32+0x4e/0x7c
[  116.147577] EIP: 0xb7f57d05
[  116.147620] EFLAGS: 00000296 CPU: 1
[  116.147671] EAX: ffffffda EBX: 00000002 ECX: b7d9a700 EDX: 09d5b008
[  116.147757] ESI: 00000000 EDI: 0805f30f EBP: 00000006 ESP: bfe8e508
[  116.147842]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 0033 SS: 007b
[  116.147929] Kernel Offset: 0x1d000000 from 0xc1000000 (relocation range: 0xc0000000-0xf7ffdfff)
[  116.148047] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
[  116.148047]
```

and then it freezes.

Any and all help related to this would be appreciated.

Edit: The CPU is **Intel x86** (**i386**) and I installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS **i386** on the USB stick.

Comment: Can't find a Fast Boot or Secure Boot option.

Comment: The mobo is some cheap one from 2009 so it may not even have such tech. Been looking for Fast Boot and Secure Boot or any other **<something>** Boot for 10 minutes now and just can't find anything.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time anyway!

Comment: Check the ISO used to make the LiveUSB for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: Yeah, I'm very new and I'm super confused by this. Wanna explain in chat?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently random failures like this are difficult to diagnose. A couple of things you can try are the following:

- Re-download the ISO and re-create the USB stick. Then boot off of it and instead of "Try Ubuntu" select "Check disk integrity". Only if that's successful, try to actually boot off the stick.
- Try using a different USB stick.
- Try using a different USB port. (Especially on older hardware, sometimes not all ports boot properly.)

I'd also suggest you try using 18.04 and not the older 16.04, should you be hitting a kernel bug, that might be fixed. As you are using a i386 system, you unfortunately can't use the official 18.04 image, as Ubuntu dropped 32 bit support in 18.04. However different flavors still support it. If that's an option for you, you can find the flavors [here.](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavourshere.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it today, but I had to get 16.04 because my hardware is i386 and I couldn't seem to find 18.04 i386.

Comment: Oh, I see! You could try a different flavor - I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I ditched Ubuntu

Comment: Did you find a flavor that works? If so, it would be cool, if you marked your question as solved by marking my answer as correct. :)